# Problemas con acceso a Servlet mediante llamada Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

Buenas a todos, a ver si alguien podría echarme una mano para resolver un problema que estoy teniendo.

Estoy intentando acceder a un Servlet de java desde una llamada Ajax por JavaScript, hasta ahí todo encajaría, pero cuando realizo la propia llamada al Servlet me devuelve el siguiente error:

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.ajax is not a function

Pongo el código para situarse:

En un Evento `onClick()` llamo a la función que realiza la llamada Ajax al Servlet.

```
        onClick: function() {
            this.ConectaServlet();
          },
        ConectaServlet: function() {

          var pOrigen = this.getView().byId("idButton1").getText();
          var oParameters = {
             "pOrigen": pOrigen
          };

          if (pOrigen) {

               this.doAjaxConecta("Conecta", oParameters, "POST", true)
                .success(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    oModel.setData(data);
                })
                .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    if(jqXHR.status && jqXHR.status != 200) {
                        jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.MessageBox");
                        sap.m.MessageBox.alert("Error producido al acceder 
                          al Servlet: "+jqXHR.responseText);
                    } 
                    else {
                        jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.MessageBox");
                        sap.m.MessageBox.alert("producido al acceder al 
                           Servlet: "+jqXHR.responseText);
                    }           
                })
                .complete(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    errores = this.tratamientoMensajesRetorno(oModel);
                })

           } 
         },

   doAjaxConecta: function(action, content, type, async) {      
        var serviceURL = this.getUrl(SERVICE_PATH + 
                         "pruebaServlet?action=");

        var params = {
                url: serviceURL + action,
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function() {
                    try {
                        //var oBusyIndicator =
                        // sap.ui.getCore().byId("idBusyIndicator");
                        // oBusyIndicator.setVisible(true);
                    } catch(e){

                    }
                },
                contentType: "application/json",
                context: this,
                cache: false
        };

        params["type"] = type || "POST";

        if (async === false) {
            params["async"] = async;
        }

        if (content) {
            params["data"] = JSON.stringify(content);
        }

        return jQuery.ajax(params);
    },      

    getUrl : function(sUrl) {
        if (sUrl == "")
            return sUrl;
        if (window.location.hostname == "localhost") {
            return "proxy" + sUrl;
        } else {
            return sUrl;
        }
    }
```

El problema me da cuando ejecuto la aplicación y accede a la llamada `doAjaxConecta` donde no me reconoce `jQuery.ajax(params);`. Alguien podría darme alguna pista de porque me salta dicho error.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas Javier Domínguez Pérez, he probado a incluir el script de jquery en la página de html, de la siguiente manera:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

```
    <script src="https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-compactVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"conexionapplet": ""}'>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

        <script>
        sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
            new sap.m.Shell({
                app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                    height : "100%",
                    name : "conexionapplet"
                })
            }).placeAt("content");
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
</body>
```

Después vuelvo a ejecutar y me vuelve a indicar el mismo error:
     Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.ajax is not a function.

¿Dónde tendría que indicarle el Script de jQuery, en la página html o donde hago la llamada al evento onClick()?.

Saludos.

Comment: Comentar que el Servlet se encuentra en el mismo proyecto que las llamadas Javascript y lo intento ejecutar en localhost. Necesitaría ayuda urgente puesto que estoy bastante atascado en este tema y no puedo continuar.  Saludos y gracias